# Can I ask which program to use to order my library?

Tags: discussion, scope

I know it looks off-topic, on the other hand people interested in literature tend to have vast libraries so they met the same problem I am facing now: how to find a book out of the 12k books in my library? (ok: they are already sorted by author surname, but yesterday I looked for a book having the title but I was mistaken with the author so I drove mad).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site! This really depends on what type of question you're asking. On one hand, this site has a [library-and-information-science](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library-and-information-science) tag. On the other hand, this site closes recommendation questions, and if you're asking for a recommendation...that might get closed. But I don't really know, because we haven't had a similar question posted on the site, and I have no idea how the community would react. A lot would depend on the specific text of the question.

I would recommend posting the question on the main site and seeing how the community would react. All anyone can offer right now on meta is speculation, since we don't have the text of the question and we don't have any policies about this. If you post the text of the question, then if it turns out that the question is off-topic, we can suggest improvements to make it acceptable and so on.